# Magento 2 product changes not reflecting on frontend after updating from admin

Tags: magento2, price, catalog, frontend, upgrade

I update catalog price from admin, but the changes is not reflecting on frontend. This needs to deploy static content and cache flush every-time, I change something in admin.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Cache clean or flush is require but if you do not want flush you can disable cache by this command :: php bin/magento cache:disable

Answer (score 4):

Please execute below queries if you are not able to fix the issue using 
bin/magento indexer:reindex command

Please note : this is only tested for single stores

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_text where store_id != 0; 
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_datetime where store_id != 0; 
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal where store_id != 0; 
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_int where store_id != 0; 
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar where store_id != 0;
```

Comment: Any reason why it was saved as `store 1 and store 0` in single store Magento?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri One possible reason which i had in my store was, At the time of CSV import I mentioned it 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to run the two following commands:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush 
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price
```

Hope it will reflect as you need.

Comment: without using reindex and cache flush , how can i get it

Comment: first of changes in index management Update by Schedule and schedule a cron for indexing.